# Is it possible to decrypt a PGP file using only the Public key and Passphrase, without the need for the private key?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bouncycastle

I have a task at hand that requires decrypting a PGP file using only the public key and passphrase, without access to the private key. The client has not provided the private key and insists on using only the public key for decryption. I need to determine if it's possible to accomplish this using Java or an external library.

if it is possible can someone to provide me with help regarding the code reference and the required library?

Comment: A file encrypted with a private key is essentially *not* encoded, since anyone can use the public key (which is *intended* for publication) to decrypt it

Answer (score 1):

PGP implements a symmetric-key encryption scheme combined with a key-exchange mechanism protected by *asymmetric*-key encryption.  The (public, private) keypairs involved are for the asymmetric part.

In asymmetric-key cryptography, the message is encrypted with one key and decrypted with a different key.  This allows a party to keep one of the keys confidential (therefore called the private key), and publish the other.

If the party holding the private key uses it to encrypt a message, then anyone (who has the public key) can decrypt that message.  This provides no confidentiality, but it authenticates that the contents of the message were encrypted by the party holding the private key.  On the other hand, if any party encrypts a message with the public key, then only the party holding the private key can decrypt it.  This provides confidentiality, but no authentication.

The passphrase is only indirectly involved. It is for protecting a key -- usually a private one -- at rest on disk.  The passphrase does not enable you to obtain the other key of the pair.

The client is following correct protocol by refusing to disclose their private key, but if you need it for decrypting the file then the client is using PGP incorrectly.  Most likely, however, the file in question is encrypted with their private key, *in which case you need the **public** one to decrypt it*, not the private one.  You should try to decrypt using the key they provide.

Answer (score 0):

Think about your question. The public key is (potentially) known by everyone. What is the passphrase used for? How much encryption would you call it if everyone can read the message?

But the beauty about asymmetrical encryption is that it serves a purpose either way. There are just three scenarios, since you should only hold your own private and public keys and some public keys of other people.

- If you encrypt with your private key, only someone holding the public key can read the message -> that is everyone and the message can only have been written using the private key. Therefore the author is known. -> digital signature
- If you encrypt with someone's public key, only that someone holding the matching private key can read the message. The recipient is known -> secret/encrypted message
- If you encrypt a message using your own public key, only you can decrypt the message. You successfully hide something from the world.